# Access content of javascript event message

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to access the content of an event message. I've copied the code below from the calendly website. However, I can't seem to access the actual message to check it and subsequently do stuff.

```
// calendly event listener
function isCalendlyEvent(e) {
  return e.data.event &&
         e.data.event.indexOf('calendly') === 0;
};

window.addEventListener(
  'message',
  function(e) {
    if (isCalendlyEvent(e)) {
      console.log(e.data);
      if(e.data == 'calendly.event_type_viewed') {
        doStuff();
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I've tried `if(e.data.event == 'calendly.event_type_viewed')`

and `if(e.data.value == 'calendly.event_type_viewed')`

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(e.data);`?

Comment: It's: `Object { event: "calendly.event_type_viewed" }`

Comment: That means `if(e.data.event == 'calendly.event_type_viewed')` should work. Are you positive `doStuff()` isn't called when you use that?

Comment: I tried `console.log('success')` and nothing was logged.

Comment: I'm not seeing any wrong with the approach, can you create a [mre] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm an idiot, the site is behind cloudflare which has cached the javascript file. I thought it was in development mode, but had switched back…

Comment: Late to the party here -- I'm a bit clueless where you're adding the code above @Badger

Comment: I can't even remember, but if you see the comment above, it was in a linked file and it was being cached by Cloudflare. Once I put Cloudflare in development mode, it worked fine.